# Cloud Task not executing Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-iam, google-tasks-api

I wanted to add security to my Cloud Function so I removed the `allUsers` access to call it - so I could instead only call it from a service account within my GCP.

So I have followed the tutorial in the [GCP docs exactly](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/samples/cloud-tasks-create-http-task-with-token):

**Cloud Function**

```
async function createTask(taskName, functionToFire, payload, fireAt){
    const tasksClient = new CloudTasksClient()
    const projectId = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId
    console.log(`${taskName} will fire ${functionToFire} at ${fireAt}...`)
    const location = 'us-central1'
    const queuePath = tasksClient.queuePath(projectId, location, taskName)
    const url = `https://us-central1-${PROJECT_ID}.cloudfunctions.net/task/${functionToFire}`
    const serviceAccountEmail = 'cloud-tasks@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
    // const sendAt = Date.now() / 1000 + 10 // plus 10 seconds of current epoch
    const task = {
        httpRequest: {
          httpMethod: 'POST',
          url,
          oidcToken: {
            serviceAccountEmail
          },
          body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64'),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        },
        scheduleTime: {
          seconds: (fireAt / 1000) // Convert millis to seconds
        }
    }
    await tasksClient.createTask({ parent: queuePath, task })
    return 200;
}
```

**Cloud Function permissions**

The service account has been given the following permissions on this specific function called `task`:

- Cloud Functions Admin
- Cloud Functions Invoker
- Cloud Functions Service Agent

[image]

However when the task actually fires, it gives this error:

`PERMISSION_DENIED(7): HTTP status code 403`

i've also had the following error:

`UNAUTHENTICATED(16): HTTP status code 401`

I've tested using 2 service accounts - the recommended one using the docs (shown above) and also a service account I created specifically for this called `cloud-tasks@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

I also went to the generic IAM page and checked the permissions of these service accounts:

1. Default service account:

[image]

2. Service account I created:

[image]

Both return the `PERMISSION_DENIED` or `UNAUTHENTICATED` errors shown above when the function fires:

[image]

Any idea what the problem is? I've tried almost everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to put the audience in your OIDC token definition. You can find the object definition in the [nodeJS documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/2.3.1/google.cloud.tasks.v2.IOidcToken.html)

```
...
...
 const task = {
        httpRequest: {
          httpMethod: 'POST',
          url,
          oidcToken: {
            serviceAccountEmail: serviceAccountEmail
            //Audience is the raw URL, without extra path or query parameter
            audience: https://us-central1-${PROJECT_ID}.cloudfunctions.net/task           },
...
...
```

Comment: Thought that was optional but yes that indeed fixed the problem. Thankyou!

Comment: Based on this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-tasks#node.js), I thought `audience` is not required, but it turns out that adding it fixed the problem for me.